# Spark on YARN via JDBC Thrift?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, thrift

When executing queries via the Thrift interface, how do I tell it to run the queries over YARN?

I'm trying to get Spark's JDBC/ODBC Thrift interface to run Spark-SQL calls on YARN. This combination seems to be absent from the documentation. The Spark on YARN docs give a bunch of options, but doesn't describe which configuration file in which to put them so that the Thrift server will pick them up.

I see a few of the settings mentioned in spark-env.sh (cores, executer memory, etc), but I can't figure out where to tell it to use YARN in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the Thriftserver use YARN for execution, it is necessary to start the thriftserver with the "--master yarn" parameter. This parameter can be appended to sbin/start-thriftserver.sh. Appending it here passes it through to the spark-submit script, which starts the server with that executor.

There is no equivalent in a config file.